# mod_python with bottle framework on apache 2.2

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, mod-python

I'm using `Apache 2.2` `Python 2.5` and want to use the bottle micro-framework.
The problem here is, that i need to install mod_wsgi to run it with my apache, but there are no binary files for windows with Python 2.5 support.
So i tried to compile it from the source but it won't work, i searched and tried for hours.

Now my question is, is there a way i can use mod_python with the apache 2.2 and bottle?
And what are the configurations I have to make? What am i supposed to look after as i'm programming my python scripts?

Sorry if this is obvious, but I could'nt find anything about this topic, even in the bottle docs...

Anyone knows pls?

Comment: "It won't work" means what? How does it fail?

Comment: The problem is, that `Python 2.5` is compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 and so I need this programm to compile my mod_wsgi.so from source. I tried to compile it like in the description on their website, but there is a problem with windows 7 and i dont have a copy of win xp. Plus I dont have enough time to waste for such things, because this is my bachelor thesis and I'm running out of time...

Comment: Why do you still need Python 2.5?

Comment: Graham himself? Wow :D The server I'm using is only supporting `Python 2.5` and `Apache 2.2`, I can't change this fact. It's my bachelor thesis and I have to work with what I get. The server is a mini-computer running on a Heidenhain PLC, it is made for the industry and as usual they lag far behind.

Comment: I managed to compile it now from source. Do you want to have the .so file? How can I send it to you?

Answer (score 0):

May be all the bottle wants it WSGI, and mod_python can do it as well, I guess. I would try [this article](http://grisha.org/blog/2013/10/10/mod-python-performance/) and basic example avaliable with bottle. If I would find a solution I'll update the answer.